# Language Culture reverting to default upon ASP login

Tags: c#, asp.net, culture

I am having some trouble with using `CurrentCulture` to display Welsh/English content. Consider the following:

I have a `MasterPage` which contains 2 headers and 2 footers, which are in English/Welsh. I have this code block inside my `Page_Load` event for the `MasterPage`:

```
    if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() == "cy-GB")
    {                
        Footer1.Visible = false;
        Footer2.Visible = true;
        Header1.Visible = false;
        Header2.Visible = true;
    }

    if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() == "en-GB")
    {                
        Footer2.Visible = false;
        Footer1.Visible = true;
        Header1.Visible = true;
        Header2.Visible = false;
    }
```

I have a link in the Welsh and English version of the header called `languagelink` which triggers a change of culture, like so:

**header.cy-GB.ascx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string currentPage = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();

            //The culture is welsh, set the language change link to English
            if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() == "cy-GB")
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(currentPage);
                languagelink.HRef = String.Format(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) + "?lang=en-GB");
            }
        }
```

**header.en-GB.ascx.cs**

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string currentPage = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();                      

            //The culture is English, set the language change link to Welsh
            if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() == "en-GB")
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(currentPage);
                languagelink.HRef = String.Format(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) + "?lang=cy-GB");
            }
         }
```

This is all working perfectly well, however on my 'Home' page you must login using ASP membership, and I have noticed that if I click on the `languagelink` button to switch to Welsh, and then login, the culture is back as "en-GB" once I pass through to the next page. I was under the impression that once the culture had been changed it would remain in that state until the application says otherwise. From the Login Page the user is redirected to `Default.aspx` where the following executes:

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class Secure_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string debug = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();
            RoleRedirect();
        }

        public void RoleRedirect()
        {
            if (MembershipUtil.IsCurrentUserAdmin())
            {

                if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() == "en-GB")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Secure/Admin/Default.aspx");               
                }

                if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() == "cy-GB")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Secure/Admin/Default.aspx?lang=cy-GB");                
                }         

            }
            else
            {
                if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() == "en-GB")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Secure/CustomerSummary.aspx");         
                }

                if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() == "cy-GB")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Secure/CustomerSummary.aspx?lang=cy-GB");          
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

If I set the language to Welsh when I step through the `MasterPage` and header page loads the culture is welsh and everything as I would expect. When I login however and step though again, when the breakpoint hits the `string debug` line on `Default.aspx.cs`, the culture is back to `en-GB` even though it was set to Welsh? Can anyone suggest what might be happening here?

**edit**

I probably should have mentioned I have created a BasePage class which all the above pages (Login, Default, CustomerSummary) are all inheriting from:

```
public partial class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        string qs = Request.QueryString["lang"];
        if (qs != null)
        {
            string language = null;
            language = Request.QueryString["lang"].ToString();
            UICulture = language;
            Culture = language;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
            base.InitializeCulture();
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the current thread culture? You must set the current culture on each call since separate requests can be serviced by different threads.

Comment: the change of culture is set upon clicking the languagelink link, this will add a querystring to the URL

Comment: Where are you actually setting the current thread culture? Do you have some code that looks for the query string parameter and does an assignment to Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture? Note that the culture assignment must be done for every page request.

Comment: See edit, I have a class which handles this and all pages mentioned are inheriting from this

Comment: Are you passing the 'lang' parameters on all page requests? If not, that would be the reason for why you lose the culture. If you do not wish to pass the query string parameter on each and every request, you can bind it to the session (when initially selected in your 'select culture page') and then use the session value to set the current culture in your InitializeCulture implementation.

Comment: @user469104 Write this as the answer and I will accept and this was what sorted it for me, also mention that every target page must inherit from the BasePage class as this was another factor